# ASIHTTPRequest zlib decompression

Tags: iphone, ios, asihttprequest, zlib

I'm trying to decompress some data that Im getting which is being compressed with zlib but Im getting a warning in my code that I'm not sure how to correct.

```
- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{

    responseData = [request responseData]; //Pass compressed data from server over to NSData variable might use to check size
    NSData *uncompressedResponseData = [[NSData alloc] init];
    uncompressedResponseData = [[request responseData] zlibInflate];  //error here

    //Is this where I have to think about decompression? or do I pass this data out to another method?
}
```

The error reads as

```
Receiver type 'NSData' for instance message dose not declare a method with selector 'zlibInflate'
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're calling a method, `zlibInflate`, on an object which doesn't support that method: `NSData` represents some arbitrary data, and doesn't know anything about uncompressing data.

Are you sure you want to be attempting to deflate the data you get back anyway? Doesn't ASIHTTPRequest handle the inflating for you (if the server returned gzip'd data)?

What happens if you just treat the `NSData` you get back as if it's already been inflated?

Also see the [changelog](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/Changelog), in particular the part titled "On-the-fly gzip decompression".

Comment: yea, I think Im just going to have to go with gzip because I'm making no progress on zlib stuff. I just get back a random bunch of numbers without treating the data.

Comment: Is the server you're fetching the data from definitely compressing the data with zlib? If so, have you tried uncompressing the data you get back with the zlib library?

Comment: What do you mean when you say 'does zlib support on-the-fly'? Do you mean 'can it do stream-based decompression'? "on-the-fly" doesn't make sense in the context of zlib itself. In the context of ASIHTTP, on the fly means that the ASI lib with transparently uncompress the gzip'd data sent from the server for you.

Comment: Weel I read somewhere (not that I can find it now.. I have looked everywhere) but I read somewhere that when you decompress a zlib file you have to store the contence into a file before you can parse/use it at all. Im not sure if this right its just something that I came across when I was trying to find out how to parse wih asihttprequest